# Looping through database with random number generation

Tags: vb.net

When adding a new DataRow, on of the items gets a random number from 100000000 to 999999999.

I need to loop through the data when this number is created to make sure it isn't there already. ( yes for a number this big chances are it will not ever be there) On the off chance that it is there, I need to generate a new number and loop through the data again.

I need to generate a random number until the random number does not match one in the database. I just can't seem to get my head around the logic today.

Here is the only thing I could come up with and I am not sure if it will work.

```
Dim TaskID As Integer
Do
    intMergeID = Merge.RandomNumber()

    For Each GetTask As DataRow In MasterDBDataSet.DBTasks
        TaskID = GetTask.Item("MergeID")
        If TaskID = intMergeID Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Loop Until intMergeID <> TaskID
```

Comment: I actually think this will work. It is kind of hard to test, but it works when nothing is found.

Comment: You can use `Dim dr as DataRow = MasterDBDataSet.DBTasks.Select("MergeID="+intMergeID.ToString)(0)` and then `If dr Is Nothing` there's no number in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a pretty straightforward bit of logic.

You need to:

1. Generate the number
2. Check for the value in the database
3. If it exists go back to 1
4. If it doesn't exist then add it

A recursive function could do this pretty well. Some pseudo code for the function is:

```
Function CheckDatabase(ByVal number As Long) as Bool
    Run database query
    if(queryResult returns true)
        generate new number
        CheckDatabase(newNumber)
    Else
        Add to database
End Function
```